# Организация подсчета товаров SQL

Tags: sql

хотел бы узнать, делают ли такую (картинка) организацию вообще. Чтобы в таблице-посреднике помимо нужных foreign key были и еще другие колонки, например, count. Или количество нужно вычислять запросом. Если это плохо - объясните, пожалуйста, почему. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите, хотя бы кратко, что обозначает каждая сущность/таблица на вашей картинке

Comment: делают, называется связь "многие ко многим"

Comment: Делайте как вам больше подходит, считать можно в запросе, используя ```count(table.column)``` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp

Comment: Герман борисов: кратко - связь многие ко многим, (корзина/продукты). Но только с добавлением колонки count. Если product добавляется, но такой product уже существует, тогда не добавляем, а count увеличиваем.

Comment: Просто созрела мысль так сделать, но ни у кого такого подхода не видел еще. Про count спасибо, про него знаю.